# Jhipster executable jar with undertow does not work - 404

Tags: jhipster

I built a jhipster application. Added an entity. Built it with

```
mvn -Pprod package
```

Application runs fine with tomcat when I use

```
java -jar xyz.war
```

But, since we need Undertow for high load scenarios and fast startup time, I simply change the maven dependency from Tomcat to Undertow in all the places (all the profiles) wherever tomcat starter dependency was mentioned as per the Spring documentation : [Using Undertow in Place of Tomcat](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-undertow-instead-of-tomcat)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This runs fine when run from Eclipse and I can see the requests are now served by Undertow and not Tomcat as logs print XNIO as the thread-id.

But., when I again build it and try to run it with `java -jar xyz.war`,

Application boots up fine but when I hit the URLs

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081
```

or http://127.0.0.1/xyz

it says not found.

What else do I need to do to put jHipster application with Undertow embedded to work?

Any quick help appreciated as a critical POC to push jHipster in our organization hinges on this step.

Comment: We used to support undertow with our fast profile but we are dropping that in our next release since there is no need for a fast profile now and undertow doesnt support websockets the last time we checked. So from you post seems like you are trying to run with dev profile. Did you try to run it in prod profile as well?

Comment: What jhipster version are you using btw?  If its 2.27 or less, then generate an app and try running `mvn -Pfast package` and then  `java -jar xyz.war -Dspring.profiles.active=fast,dev` without modifying anything which should use undertow by default

Comment: Hi Deepu, thanks for noticing this thread and responding. I tried with --spring.profiles.active=dev,fast but I think it is falling back to tomcat and is not really booting Undertow. When I subject the application to gatling test with rampusers(900)  and open visual VM, I notice that the threads created have names starting like 'nio....', and the number of threads

Comment: When I subject the application to Gatling test with rampusers(900)  and open visual VM, I notice that the threads created have names starting like 'nio....', and the number of threads created are around 215. If I simply change the pom dependency to 'spring-boot-starter-undertow' and run it through eclipse with the help of main method, the thread naming convention seen in visual vm is that they start with 'XNIO.. and total number of threads used is just 50 through out Gatling test of 900 users.

Comment: And the version of jHipster I am using is 2.27

Comment: I had missed on the -Pfast while building, but result is same - not found. (With -D Arg as fast,dev). Basically, any profile, the fat jar doesn't work with undertow. It somehow works through only main method execution through eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, a solution for the nemesis is in place. Here is an update from me -  Today, I started to debug spring boot and undertow code and realized that spring boot is looking for resources in the below locations :

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };
```

After that, I created a folder called resources inside the META-INF directory and copied all the resources inside it using 7zip. ***And lo & behold., it works! :-).***

Although spring boot is supposed to also load resources from

```
private static final String[] SERVLET_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = { "/" };
```

for some reason, it is not doing so. (which is where jHipster is putting all of the resource files)

I thought this to be a bug with spring boot version that jHipster uses and I upgraded my app spring boot version to  `1.3.3.RELEASE` , but that does not help either.

Answer (score 3):

We used to support Undertow, but removed it recently. So you shouldn't have much trouble setting it up back (and what you do looks good, then you don't post your whole configuration so it's hard to tell).
Anyway, concerning your specific use-case, you need to know why we removed Undertow:

- Start-up time is indeed lower, by something like 300-500ms. We were mostly using this in our "dev" profile, as start-up time is important. But now that we have the Spring Dev Tools hot restart, this isn't useful at all anymore.
- For "prod" usage, I haven't seen any performance difference between Tomcat and Undertow. Compared to just one database access (costing several ms), I guess you can't see this kind of improvements.

Besides, we have removed Undertow because it lacks a number of important features for us. Most importantly:

- GZip compression support -> as you will lose this, your performance will in fact be much worse with Undertow than with Tomcat
- Websocket support

Last but not least, it's easy to scale up your JHipster application by adding new nodes (and it will be even easier in JHipster 3.0), so handling a large number of users shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Hi Julien, Thanks for your response. But it is really unfortunate if you guys have decided not to support Undertow.  For us, primary use case for Undertow are these : 1. It is consuming far too less CPU resources. Total number of threads spawned by Undertow where around 56, while tomcat spawned around 215 for a Gatling Test  of rampusers(900). By default, Undertow spawns only 1 worker threads per CPU & 10 task threads per CPU. While Tomcat could execute only 75% total requests in less than 800ms, Undertow could do around 81% requests while using only 55 threads.

Comment: AFA Gzipping is considered, our plan was to anyway deploy static content behind nginx and for responses of Rest APIs, I guess gzipping for them could be done too in nginx.  (On a side note, I am working on enhancing jHipster POM to emit a separate Zip containing static content at build time so that they can be deployed on reverse proxy servers - may be I will contribute it back to jHipster back if community thinks that's useful)

Comment: AFA websocket support is considered, Undertow says it has full support for it. http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.3.0/index.html

Comment: Just a note : All performance tests I mentioned above were after I manually put all the loggers to ERROR mode using jHipster console.                                  And this is the only change I did to test it with a fat jar :  remove spring-boot-starter-tomcat and add spring-boot-starter-undertow in both dev and prod profiles. Works with eclipse, does not work with java -jar option.

Comment: Excellent points @SRK ! In fact this is so interesting I created a new ticket for this on our bugtracker [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2948), so we can look at switching to Undertow.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't manage to have your error. Undertow seems to work fine for me.

1) I generated a new JHipster project (from master), all default options

2) I replace tomcat by undertow only in this part of pom.xml :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- log configuration -->
            <logback.loglevel>DEBUG</logback.loglevel>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

3) Build :

```
mvn package -Pprod
```

4) Start database :

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/prod.yml up -d
```

5) Start app

```
java -jar target/*.war --spring.profiles.active=prod

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 1.3.2.RELEASE ::
:: http://jhipster.github.io ::

2016-02-22 00:18:40.051  INFO 6118 --- [           main] com.mycompany.myapp.JhundertowApp        : Starting JhundertowApp on pgrXps with PID 6118 (started by pgrimaud in /home/pgrimaud/workspace/tests2/32-undertow)
2016-02-22 00:18:40.054  INFO 6118 --- [           main] com.mycompany.myapp.JhundertowApp        : The following profiles are active: prod
2016-02-22 00:18:44.024  WARN 6118 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026009: XNIO worker was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default worker will be used
2016-02-22 00:18:44.126  WARN 6118 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
2016-02-22 00:18:44.742  INFO 6118 --- [           main] c.mycompany.myapp.config.WebConfigurer   : Web application configuration, using profiles: [prod]
```

6) I change log in app to confirm it runs with undertow

```
----------------------------------------------------------
    Application 'jhundertow' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://127.0.0.1:8080
    External:   http://127.0.1.1:8080
----------------------------------------------------------
2016-02-22 00:20:20.585 TRACE 6118 --- [ XNIO-2 task-31] c.m.m.c.l.AngularCookieLocaleResolver    : Parsed cookie value [%22en%22] into locale 'en'
2016-02-22 00:20:25.741 TRACE 6118 --- [ XNIO-2 task-32] c.m.m.c.l.AngularCookieLocaleResolver    : Parsed cookie value [%22en%22] into locale 'en'
```

Comment: @SRK may be follow what pgrimaud did on a new app and then compare it with your setup

Comment: Yes. I just tried the same thing, but no matter what I do, result is same - not found. This is on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: This is my yo-rc on a win7 : '{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "baseName": "cfepoc6",
    "packageName": "com.ev.cfe",
    "packageFolder": "com/ev/cfe",
    "authenticationType": "xauth",
    "hibernateCache": "no",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
    "websocket": "no",
    "databaseType": "mongodb",
    "devDatabaseType": "mongodb",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mongodb",
    "searchEngine": "no",
    "useSass": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "frontendBuilder": "grunt",
    "enableTranslation": false,
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
       "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ]
  }
}'

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately for me, when I move the same war file to a RHEL system, it works just fine. :-) I am accepting @pgrimaud 's answer. Thanks @deepu and @Julien. You guys are awesome.

I will investigate what's going wrong on my Win7 machine-will post back here if I am able to figure out. (npm clear cache dint help. Will re-install node.js and npm as I had updated them for my other node.js work - I will see if that helps). I will also try to debug spring-boot-starter-undertow.